# How to exclude path/files from git-diff-index

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

I have a sh file that runs pre-commit stage but I want to exclude some paths but I also want to know how to exclude files that ends with "*Test" for example.

Here's my sh file;

```
for FILE in `git-diff-index HEAD 2>&1 --name-only | sed 's/^:.*     //' | uniq` ; do
```

I know that this exclude path can be written with **git-diff-index** but I don't know how to write it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git-diff-index HEAD 2>&1 --name-only -- . ':(exclude)*Tests.java' -- . ':(exclude)*Test.java' -- . ':(exclude)*\as\*' | sed 's/^:.*     //' | uniq`

This works well for both path and specific files

Answer (score 2):

You can use [magic pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) to exclude some of the paths. For example

```
git diff-index HEAD -- :!*Test
```

would exclude all files that end with `Test`.

<sub>Minor compatibility note: do not use the dashed form `git-diff-index`, because support for it will be dropped; use the command form `git diff-index`.</sub>

Comment: @dani Which part of the cited documentation is unclear? Are you looking for `**`?